# How to check if submitting form with jQuery if successful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have following codes as form, and I wanted to check if the form is been successfully submitted.

I was wondering how I can check on the console. I want to check if the form is been successfully submitted so I can display another form.

```html
<form id="signup" data-magellan-target="signup" action="http://app-service-staging.com" class="epic_app-signup" method="POST">
  <div class="grid__column " style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Name" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__column " style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="grid__column " style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="text" name="confimred-password" placeholder="Confirmed password" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid__column " style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate" min="2019-12-16">
  </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="grid__column" style="width: 50%;"></button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and the script,

```
  $('.epic_app-signup').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('.epic_app-signup').serializeArray();
    var jsonData = {};
    formData.forEach(function(item, index) {
      jsonData[item.name] = item.value;
    });
    console.log('data\n', jsonData);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://app-service-staging.com/api/auth/register',
      type:'POST',
      data: jsonData,
      contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (textStatus === 'success') {

        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If you're submitting the form normally, then it's not possible as the original page will have been unloaded. If you're using AJAX to submit the form then hook a `done()` or `success` callback to listen for a 200 OK response and to read the returned data

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for your reply and yes i've tried above.

Comment: Try different order: `function(textStatus, data, jqXHR)` usually it's first parameter the response and second the data. Or perhaps `console.log` them all

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by various ways currently you are not using ajax request if you want to achieve this without ajax let follow these steps

- when user click on submit button your form is submitted received form information(you define the path in action attribute where form submitted) after processing successfully  redirect toward a new form

second solution use jquery ajax request

```
//first form
<form action='test.php' id='form_1' method='post'>
<label>Full Name</label>
<input type='text' name='full_name'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>

//second form

<form action='test.php' id='form_2' method='post' style='display:none'>
<label>Father Name</label>
<input type='text' name='father_name'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

use jquery cdn

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js'></script>
<script>
$("#form_1").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert("form submitted successfully");
                $('#form_1').hide();
                $('#form_2').show();


           },
           error:function(data){
               alert("there is an error kindly check it now");
           }

         });

        return false;

});
</script>
```

Comment: hi do i test this on console?

Comment: simple place your code inside success: function(data)
 { console.log('submitted successfully') }
if there is any error then error section will be executed